# how do we share the frames with images in iOS App like VideoCollage App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to iOS.

Please any one help me to do this.

I took `pageViewController` with 5 pages. Every `ViewController` has 12 buttons. When we click any button that corresponding button image placed in next view.

In that page button image contains image views when we click every image view we will get image from gallery which should be in zoom and that image view has background image. That is frame..

Did well till now. But my issue is how to share the frames with images like videoCollage App...

Comment: please elaborate little more it too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get frame of any kind of UIView like UIImageView object

```
//Get image view  controller frame 
CGRect frameOfImage=imgView.frame;
```

And also ,

If you want to get the 'size' of the assigned image , here we go

```
//Get photo(image) frame
CGSize sizeOfImage = imgView.image.size;
```

This will give you height & width of the image.

Comment: my issue is how to share the photo frames with photos ..please anyone send me the related links or code...because i am new iOS..thank you

Comment: @vanidasariios For 'photo' i meant here 'image'(UIImage object).I have given you the code itself.